# Collect Specific Rows from txt file

Tags: python, matlab, wolfram-mathematica

[sample of the txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rmL2.png)

I want to extract the whole lines from a txt file which has ***NVSS*** keyword and export it as a new txt file but I have no idea how to do this.
Thank you

Comment: Elaborate your question if you want to get any answer. It's totally unclear of what you are asking, what you have tried (if you have tried something) etc

Comment: Your question should show some kind of effort. Did you try something? If yes, please share it.

Comment: if you dont care what language, `grep NVSS file.txt>out.txt`

Comment: @agentp well it doesn't matter what language; I don't understand what do you mean by grep NVSS file.txt>out.txt , Could you please explain more

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract every line containing 'NVSS' into a new file:

```
with open('infile.txt', 'r') as infile, open('outfile.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        if 'NVSS' in line:
            outfile.write(line)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, brilliant and simple